# How to create DOM elements on $.Ajax() Success using jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm creating a dynamic list of `checkbox` on `$.ajax` :

```
 function load() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "*************",
            data: "************",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (x, e) { alert(e.responseText); },
            success: function (objTrendList) {
                $.each(objTrendList, function (index, value) {
                    // append the checkbox panels to tool div 
            $('#tools').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_' +
            value.LngTrendID + '" checked="checked" value="0" />&nbsp;<div 
            style="display:inline;">' + value.StrTrendName + '</div><br />');

                });
             } 
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        load();
        console.log($('#tools :checkbox')); // i know I don't get any thing here 
        because the this line is called before the ajax function 

    });
```

i know I don't get any thing with the console.log line  because the this line is called before the ajax function

*Question* How can i load the ajax function first i though when i do `$(document).ready()` it will run last 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the ajax call and use the already built in deferred object in $.ajax :

```
function load() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "*************",
        data: "************",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (x, e) { alert(e.responseText); },
        success: function (objTrendList) {
            $.each(objTrendList, function (index, value) {
                // append the checkbox panels to tool div 
        $('#tools').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_' +
        value.LngTrendID + '" checked="checked" value="0" />&nbsp;<div 
        style="display:inline;">' + value.StrTrendName + '</div><br />');

            });
         } 
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    load().done(function() {
        console.log($('#tools :checkbox')); // i know I don't get any thing here 
    });
});
```

Comment: It's been a while since I played with `jQuery.ajax()`, but potentially, would `async: false` allow for the code to work, otherwise, as written? (I realise that `async: false` is...not pleasant in terms of UI, but as a theoretical alternative.)

Comment: i got this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined `

Comment: @DavidThomas - Yes, async false would wait until the ajax call was completed, and you'd get the right result in the console.log, but it freezes the browser and is as you say not a very good alternative.

Comment: @MinaGabriel - what version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: well if your page depends on that ajax call because you need to run it first, then it IS synchronous behaviour and maybe you show some loading indicator before your ajax call completes. You can call it with the body onload event.

Comment: @MinaGabriel - that's strange, and you did add the return statement at the top as well ??

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't have anything in the log is because $.ajax is asynchronous (the first 'A' in AJAX stands for 'Asynchronous'). Meaning that when you call your `load()` function, it fires off the `$.ajax` call, but does not wait for the `$.ajax` call to return before `load()` returns (this is why you must specify a `success` and `error` function so it know what to do when it actually does return).

We can look at a timeline of how your code gets executed:

1. load()

   1. $.ajax()
   2. return (null)
2. console.log()
3. (some indeterminate time later) success()

`$.ajax()` returns a type of object that knows when it has returned from it's call. Therefore you can call `.done()` on the object and execute code in that function that will wait until after the `success()` has run.

therefore if you return the `$.ajax` call you will be able to call `.done()` and do things with your newly-added inputs.

```
function load() {
    return $.ajax({...});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    load().done(function(){
        console.log($('#tools :checkbox'));
    });
});
```